# C++ Template pointer-based variable results in garbage being returned unless stored and outputted before

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

For an assignment I'm implementing a hash map. My valueOf() function is returning garbage in main even though its finding the key's value and outputting it in the function. I've found 2 possible solutions, but neither are suitable for my case.

Class overview:

**HashTable**

```
template <typename V>
class HashTable {
private:
    string m_key;
    V m_value;
...
```

**MyStringMap**

```
template <typename V>
class MyStringMap : public AbstractStringMap<V> {
private:
    HashTable<V> * m_table;
    int m_maxSize;
    int m_currSize;
    string EMPTY_KEY;
    string TOMB_KEY;
...
```

**And the problem function (which is in MyStringMap):**

```
const V& valueOf(const string& key) const throw (Oops) {
    int home;
    int pos = home = hash(key);

    // stops at found key (for success) or empty key (for failed)
    for (int i = 1; (key != m_table[pos].getKey()) && (EMPTY_KEY != m_table[pos].getKey()); i++)
        pos = (home + probe(key, i)) % m_maxSize;

    // check found pos and return accordingly
    if (key == m_table[pos].getKey()) {
        return m_table[pos].getValue();
    }
    else
        throw Oops("Key Not Found!!");
}
```

The `return m_table[pos].getValue();` part above is returning garbage when outputting in main and causing the program to crash. However, having `cout << "FOUND [" << m_table[pos].getKey() << "] [" << m_table[pos].getValue() << "]" << endl;` in the function (before the return) displays the correct value.

**The way I'm running it in main is:**

```
try {
  cout << "Person1? " << thelist.valueOf("Person1") << endl;
  cout << "Person2? " << thelist.valueOf("Person2") << endl;
} catch (Oops e) {
  cout << e.getMsg() << endl;
}
```

The two solutions I found, but aren't suitable are:

- Appending `c_str()` to the end of the function in main, Ex: `cout << "Person1? " << thelist.valueOf("Person1").c_str() << endl;`. Since I can't edit main (as the assignment dictates), I can't use this.
- Returning a variable instead of the direct value AND having to output it there, Ex:

`V found = m_table[pos].getValue();
cout << "FOUND [" << m_table[pos].getKey() << "] [" << found << "]" << endl;`

For whatever reason, this makes the return display the correct non-garbage value. But, its a hacky solution and I don't want the extra output.

---

Any help would be appreciated. I'll clarify where needed as I'm sure this probably makes no sense.

Comment: [mcve], please. Sam's answer below has decent odds of being right, but why guess?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your getValue() method returns a V object. That object is created on the stack. You then return a reference to that object. Then the stack is overwriten by something else going on in your computer, and you get garbage. This would also explain why returning an object works: it is allocated in the memory space and is not overwritten.

In short, you are returning a reference to an object on the stack. You can't do that because you don't know what will be at that address when it is read later.

Comment: What is the way to properly return the value then? Assigning it to a variable and returning that variable still causes garbage unless I append .c_str() to the returned value in main.